# Are the rings $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1 \rangle$ and $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle xy-1 \rangle$ isomorphic ?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Are the rings $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1 \rangle$ and $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle xy-1 \rangle$ isomorphic ? I don't know whether any of the rings can be reduced to a simpler looking ring , and the way as it is , it is seemingly hard to find their zero divisors or idempotents . Please help

Comment: Yes. In the first, send $y\mapsto iy$. In the second send $x\mapsto x-y,y\mapsto x+y$.

Comment: Hint: With $u=x+iy$, $v=x-iy$ you get $x^2+y^2=?$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ 1 = x^2+y^2 = (x-iy)(x+iy) = XY $